# How to lift or increase BigQuery's limit on recursive iterations

Tags: google-bigquery

It seems like Google BigQuery limits the number of iterations done for recursive queries:

> A recursive CTE has reached the maximum number of iterations: 100

I cannot find any docs how to lift or at least increase this limit. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is configurable in BigQuery.

Comment: this is in preview yet, so i think there is a chance for it to be different in GA :o) obviously I am trying to be optimistic here

Comment: This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220997372). We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#:%7E:text=If%20recursion%20does%20not%20terminate%2C%20the%20query%20fails%20after%20reaching%20100%20iterations%2C%20which%20can%20be%20customized%20at%20the%20project%20level.) (emphasis mine):

> If recursion does not terminate, the query fails after reaching 100 iterations, **which can be customized at the project level.**

However, I could not find the setting in the project.

It's not in the project's [BigQuery Quota Policy](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=bigquery.googleapis.com) or [BigQuery API quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com/quotas). It's not mentioned in the [quota documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) either but it does say that one can [request quota increases](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas?#requesting_a_quota_increase) albeit [**some** quota increases](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#:%7E:text=Some%20quotas%20cannot%20be%20updated%20using%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20Console.%20If%20you%20find%20that%20you%20cannot%20change%20a%20quota%20from%20the%20console%2C%20request%20the%20increase%20from%20Cloud%20Customer%20Care) need to be requested via Cloud Customer Care.

Maybe this is one such limit or maybe we need to wait until GA... ‍♂

Answer (score 0):

The work around I came up for this was to just chain CTEs, that may or may not be possible depending on how you're doing it.

Example:

```
DECLARE StartDate DATE DEFAULT '2022-03-15';

WITH RECURSIVE
    Dates1 AS (
        SELECT
            StartDate AS Day,
            1 RowNumber,
            1 Ranking

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Day,
            RowNumber + 1 AS RowNumber,
            Ranking + 1 AS Ranking
        FROM
            Dates1
        WHERE
            Day < CURRENT_DATE()
            AND RowNumber < 100
    ),
    Dates2 AS (
        SELECT
            DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Day,
            1 AS RowNumber,
            Ranking + 1 AS Ranking
        FROM
            Dates1
        WHERE
            RowNumber = 100
            AND Day < CURRENT_DATE()

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            DATE_ADD(Day, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Day,
            RowNumber + 1 AS RowNumber,
            Ranking + 1 AS Ranking
        FROM
            Dates2
        WHERE
            Day < CURRENT_DATE()
            AND RowNumber < 100
    ),
    Dates AS (
        SELECT
            Day,
            Ranking
        FROM
            Dates1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            Day,
            Ranking
        FROM
            Dates2
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Dates
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
```