# Future forecasting based on a multiplier in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression, forecasting, recursive-query

I am trying to do semi forecasting with BigQuery. I have minutely data of users, and a minute multiplier (pre calculated based on past events) that should predict the next minute's value. I created a dataset with all future minutes for the relevant timeframe, future minute will have null value, it looks like that:

[image]

Now trying to calculate all future values based on the multiplier. I can't figure out how to apply this to more than 1 row, meaning; the first null row will be the prev value times the multiplier. But now what? How can I keep calculating it based on future values? The output should look like that:

[image]

So 100 is the only real value - then 100 * 1.1 will be 120, and then 120 * 1.2 will be 132, so on and so forth.

Appreciate the help guys, thanks!

Comment: Surely the first multiplier should be 1, or the first result be 110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think there is another way to solve this then?

Consider below approach

```
select *,
  round(first_value(value/multiplier) over win * exp(sum(ln(multiplier)) over win), 2) as new_value
from your_table
window win as (order by minute)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: The power of knowing maths (logs and cumulative sum == cumulative product)

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select minute, value, multiplier, value new_value from mytable where minute = 1
    union all
    select t.minute, t.value, t.multiplier, c.value * t.multiplier
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t on t.minute = c.minute + 1
)
select * from cte order by minute
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I tried with recursive, but since I run a minutely data-frame I can't event reach a single day of data, because of 100 iterations limitation. Any idea how to bypass?

Comment: @GMB to confirm, `mytable` is the table of OP? What does `mutable` contain?

Comment: @TomerShalhon: yes, `with recursive` is still a rather young feature in BQ... I see there is some discussion about this limitation being lifted, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062108/how-to-lift-or-increase-bigquerys-limit-on-recursive-iterations). There is also a BQ ticket about it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220997372. Not clear whether this is actually fixed yet or not.

Comment: @GMB thanks! Do you think there is another way to solve this then?

Comment: @TomerShalhon: with a fixed multiplier we could probably avoid the recursion with  with sophisticated arithmetic ; but you have varying multipliers, which is beyond my math skills I am afraid...